# Phonegap: some Javascript files do not load on device. App works on simulator

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, cordova

I've been chasing this bug for a few hours now. App works fine in simulator, but fails on device. I have been working on this app for several weeks, mostly using the simulator to debug. I wait for the device ready event, then run the following:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    setStylesheet();
    console.log("Device ready");
    try {
        startup();
    } catch (err) { console.log(err);}
}
```

The `startup` and `setStylesheet` functions are included via the following script tags, respectively.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/screens.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/stylesheets.js"></script>
```

The `setStylesheet` function fired, and the CSS is applied to the app. The startup function is not. I get the following message in the XCode console:

```
2012-05-27 13:29:34.543 app[417:307] [INFO] {"message":
"Can't find variable: startup", "line":59, "sourceId":3807368, 
"sourceURL":"file:///var/mobile/Applications/hash/app.app/www/index.html",
"expressionBeginOffset":1141, "expressionCaretOffset":1148, "expressionEndOffset":1148}
```

Running in simulator, everything runs fine. On an iphone, that error is thrown. I linted screens.js and only had warnings. What are the possible causes for something like this?

**EDIT:** A friend suggested this could be a race condition issue. I tried dynamically adding the screens.js script tag and using `tag.onload` to call the function. That doesn't seem to be it though, as I still get the same issue. `setStylesheet` was also converted to be called after onload is fired, and it still works.

Comment: Hmm weird, where is `startup` defined? just before `onDeviceReady` in `index.html`?

Comment: It is defined within screens.js.

Comment: make sure screens.js comes before your phonegap.js file.

Comment: Sprinkle some `console.log(startup);` lines, maybe last in `screens.js` and before and after  `setStylesheet()`.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald why should that file come before cordova.js?

Comment: I don't understand why, but this just started working again on the device. I added a console.log(startup) at the end of screens.js per Mattias's suggestion, tested simulator and it worked, then device and it also worked. I deleted and the device still works too. I'm going to leave the question open and keep trying to understand what exactly caused it to break down. If I figure that out, I'll answer the question. Thanks for the help everyone.

Comment: My guess is that your onDeviceReady method is being called before screens.js is loaded thereby startup() is not defined when it is called. By putting in the console.log statement you've probably changed up the timing on your page. Make sure you load screens.js before phonegap/cordova.js.

Comment: Yeah it would be great if you could include more code, at least where the `onDeviceReady` is defined.